# Slow Neo4j query from node.js

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am querying `Neo4j` database from `node.js` server and some queries sometimes run very slow and time out ultimately. I want to somehow get data in chunks in these particular cases and feed them gradually into the front end. I can't seem to find any good info on how to do that. Here is my `node.js` code:

```
router.get('/gene_expr', function(req, res) {
  var geneName = req.query.geneName;
  var datasetName = req.query.datasetName;
  const expr_query =
    'MATCH (c:Cell { DATASET: "' + datasetName + '"} )-[ex:EXPRESSES]->' +
    '(g:Gene { geneName: "' + geneName + '" }) ' +
    'WITH c, ex, g, round(avg(ex.expr)) AS AVG ' +
    'WHERE ex.expr > AVG ' +
    'RETURN c.tsneX, c.tsneY, ex.expr, c.cellId';
  console.log(expr_query);
  var driver = dbUtils.driver;
  const session = driver.session();
  session.run(
    expr_query,
    {}
  ).then(result => {
    var exprData = chartService.prepareMarkerData(result, geneName);
    res.json({
      exprData
    });

    session.close();
  });
})
```

I have never done such a thing. Would this `npm` package be good for the purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypher-stream ? If I use it, what else would I need to set up (headers, etc.) to allow for streaming data feed? On the front end I am using `axios`:

```
axios({
  method:'get',
  url:url,
  responseType:'stream'
})
.then(function (response) { ... })
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you PROFILEd your query in the browser to see if there are any problems? What indexes do you have in the database? Please attach both the output of `:schema` as well as the PROFILE plan (with all nodes expanded).

Comment: The query in your question does not seem to be doing what you intend. Due to the way [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) works, your usage of the `AVG()` function in that `WITH` clause will only attempt to take the average of a **single** `ex.expr`, round that single value down, and then the `WHERE` clause will compare the rounded down `ex.expr` value to its original value.